# CSV.open and send_data in rails....?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I may end up figuring this out later, but i thought I'd try.

Can someone help combine send_data and CSV.open

According to the docs, you can `CSV.open filename, mode(whatever that is)` and basically a file will save to your current path.  However, if you want to send that file to a user through his broswer, as most of us who give the option of CSV files to download, do,do... then can we combine the CSV.open with send_data?

thoughts?

examples welcome if you do something like this too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want to combine those two things.

CSV.open will save the data to a file, which you would need to read back in in order to send it through send_data.

But you can do something like:

```
csv = []
csv << ["titles", "for", "csv"]
csv << ["data", "for", "csv"]
send_data(csv.collect{|s| s.join(",")}.join("\n"), 
          :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', 
          :filename => "mytitle.csv")
```

Which should prompt the user to download the csv file.

Comment: Along those same lines, my blue sky thinking was to maybe make send_data part of the filename part of `CSV.open` maybe?  I see it no different then to_csv when that used to work in FasterCSV and 1.8.7.  `to_csv` just streams that bad boy and was slick. I do something similar to what you are saying now with CSV.generate, but it's so boring :-)